# How to generate minimalistic js bundle using webpack and babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to build webpack/babel config transpiring this code:

```
class Klass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  welcome() {
    return `Hello, ${this.name}`;
  }
}
window.klass = new Klass("Robot Bender");
```

into IE10 compatible js.
I don't have any third part libraries and my main requirement is bundle size.
bundle will be embedded into script tag. I am using browserlist through babel-env.
default webpack/bable config generates 10kb of code =(

Thanks fo help!